# How to inject several classes into a method (guice)?

Tags: java, reflection, guice

I have three classes (for example)

```
Buick implements Vehicle
Chevy implements Vehicle
Ferrari implements Vehicle
```

And I have a method

```
travelTo(ZipCode start, Zipcode end) 
for(Class<Vehicle> v : vehicleInstances)
{
     Vehicle car= v.getconstructor(ZipCode.class, ZipCode.class).newInstance(start,end).newInstance(start,end);

     car.drive();
}
```

I want to inject these classes (rather than using an ugly static array of class names or enum of class names), by using Guice.  How would I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the Guice Multibinder. It can Inject a `Set<Vehicle>` for you.

http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html

EDIT: You'll still probably have to Inject that as a member variable or constructor though.

EDIT: Added example code. Doing this without an IDE, so it may need some tweaks.

```
 public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
      Multibinder<Vehicle> multibinder
         = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Vehicle.class);
      multibinder.addBinding().to(Buick.class);
      multibinder.addBinding().to(Chevy.class);
      multibinder.addBinding().to(Ferrari.class);
   }
 }

 public class YourInterestingClass {
   private final Set<Vehicle> vehicles;

   @Inject
   public YourInterestingClass(Set<Vehicles> vehicles){
     this.vehicles = vehicles;
   }

   public void doSomethingWithVehicles(){
     for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicles){
       // do something
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This was helpful - An explanation of your suggested implementation of the multibinder would be useful for context here...  but in any case, your answer was useful .

Comment: @jayunit100 - Added some sample code for you. Hope it clarifies.